# Can you transfer an item bought on one PSN account to another?

Tags: psn

How do you transfer items bought from one account to another on a PS4 that has two accounts with psn plus?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can't do this.

Comment: You can't transfer items bought on one account to another, but you can access those items with another account, as long as those are already installed on the same console.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

At best you can have both accounts homed on that PS4, download the game from account #1, then logout and play from account #2. But account #1 still needs to be bound to that PS4. If you move account #1 to another PS4 then all of the games it had downloaded will be deactivated and account #2 will no longer be able to play them (you'll get an invalid licensing notice).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can't. For example, in COD, I can purchase the season pass on my dad's account and be able to play the maps on my account, but will not be able to access the DLC Gobblegums, as I techniclaly do not own it.

Answer (score 0):

Content / items purchased from the PlayStation®Store can only be used with the Sony Entertainment Network account that made the purchase. Items can not be transferred from one Sony Entertainment Network account to another.

Source-support.us.playstation.com/